# Django manytomany models views and templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-urls

Tengo el modelo Gammer que es extension de User y el modelo Competition. muchos jugadores pueden jugar una competencia y una competencia puede tener muchos jugadores (`ManyToMany`)

```
class Gammer(User):

    competition = models.ManyToManyField(Competition)
    puntaje_global = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ranking = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Competition(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    finish_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    duration = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)

    def finish(self):
        self.finish_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Agregue en admin.py:

admin.site.register(Gammer)

El admin puede visualizar competencias de jugador o asignarles competencias:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ahora yo quiero que los jugadores eligan las competencias a las que quieren subscribirse.

Creé GammerForm en forms.py (no sé si es correcto)

```
class GammerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    competition = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=models.Competition.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model=models.Gammer
        fields =('competition', )
```

¿Cómo puedo seguir para que el usuario desde su cuenta pueda unirse a las competiciones y no lo haga mas el admin? Es decir, que se listen todas las competencias y que pueda subscribirse el usuario, y si todo marcha bien el admin podría ver las competencias en las que el usuario se unió.

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo muy básico (sin usar ModelForms) para que puedas tirar del hilo:

Views:

```
def competiciones(request):
   if request.post:
       comp_add = request.post.get('competition')
       Competition.objects.create(user=request.user, comp_id = comp_add)

   comp_disponibles = Competition.objects.all()
   render(request, 'comp_disponibles.html',{'comp_disponibles':comp_disponibles})
```

template (comp_disponibles.html)

```
{% block content %}

<form method="POST">

<select id="competition" name="competition">
         {% for comp in comp_disponibles %}
           <option value="{{ comp.id }}">{{ comp.nombre }}</option>
         {% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="añadirme a la competición">
<form>

{% endblock %}
```

Esto lo que hace es generar una nueva template que contiene un form con un select que añade una a una las competiciones.

Se podría complicar más añadiendo varias competiciones o haciendo-lo por ajax, pero creo que esto es un punto de inicio.